Loyalty program including Generate Voucher Code in ASP.NET webform
Currently I'm using ASP.NET webforms for this project. Below is my  backend code for my member.aspx which is the loyalty program. It should get the customer's current points balance using session (which works fine, I can get their points balance using session and from NoSQL database). But it can't generate the code which it does not shows the code on the screen, which I'm using label to show all the generated code (can be called: redeemed vouchers).
And the points should be deducted based on the required points values, but it can't also. I should save the new points balance to my database also right? And I should have 'vouchers' in my database under the customer table to save voucher codes also? Or can I directly save into session without database?
Please help me with this, I have already spent 2 days trying to solve this problem.
I really have no clue how to solve this. Please help guys.....
SYEntities db = new SYEntities();
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

    string name = ticket.Name;

    // retrieve the member points from the database
    Customer C = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.cust_name == name);

    if (C != null)
    {
        int points = (int)C.mem_point;
        lblPoints.Text = "Your current points balance: " + points;
        Session["points"] = points;
    }

    List<string> redeemedVouchers = GetRedeemedVouchersFromSession();

    // Display redeemed vouchers on label
    if (redeemedVouchers.Any())
    {
        lblRedeemedVouchers.Text = "Redeemed vouchers: " + string.Join(", ", redeemedVouchers);
    }
    else
    {
        lblRedeemedVouchers.Text = "No vouchers redeemed yet.";
    }
}

protected void btnRedeem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnRedeem = (Button)sender;
    int pointsRequired = GetPointsRequired(btnRedeem.CommandArgument);
    int customerPoints = (int)Session["points"];

    if (customerPoints >= pointsRequired)
    {
        // Deduct points from customer's balance
        customerPoints -= pointsRequired;

        // Generate voucher code
        string voucherCode = GenerateVoucherCode(pointsRequired);

        // Save redeemed voucher
        List<string> redeemedVouchers = GetRedeemedVouchersFromSession();
        redeemedVouchers.Add(voucherCode);
        SaveRedeemedVouchersToSession(redeemedVouchers);

        // Update points balance in session
        Session["points"] = customerPoints;

        // Display success message
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "voucherRedeemed", "alert('Voucher redeemed successfully.');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        // Not enough points
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "notEnoughPoints", "alert('Your points are not enough to redeem this voucher.');", true);
    }
}

private int GetPointsRequired(string voucherCommandArgument)
{
    // Extract points required from command argument
    return int.Parse(voucherCommandArgument);
}

private string GenerateVoucherCode(int pointsRequired)
{
    // Prefix based on points required
    string prefix;

    switch (pointsRequired)
    {
        case 10:
            prefix = "1OFF";
            break;

        case 50:
            prefix = "5OFF";
            break;

        case 100:
            prefix = "10OFF";
            break;

        case 150:
            prefix = "15OFF";
            break;

        case 200:
            prefix = "25OFF";
            break;

        case 250:
            prefix = "30OFF";
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid points required.");
    }

    // Generate voucher code
    string code = prefix + GenerateRandomString(6); // Prefix + 6 random characters

    return code;
}

private string GenerateRandomString(int length)
{
    // Generate random string of specified length
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
            .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}

private List<string> GetRedeemedVouchersFromSession()
{
    // Retrieve redeemed vouchers from session or return an empty list
    return Session["redeemedVouchers"] as List<string> ?? new List<string>();
}

private void SaveRedeemedVouchersToSession(List<string> redeemedVouchers)
{
    // Save redeemed vouchers to session
    Session["redeemedVouchers"] = redeemedVouchers;
}

